# Как залить фоновый цвет в SVG изображении луны в процентах

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, svg-animation

Я хочу, чтобы  цвет фонового изображения SVG заполнялся постепенно, в процентах.

Вот изображение луны SVG. Я хочу постепенно, в процентах заполнять её белым цветом.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="139" height="134"> 
<g> 
  <circle stroke-width="7" stroke="#000" fill="#fff" r="58" cy="69" cx="69"/>
  <path stroke-width="0" fill="#000" d="m69,9 a62,60 0 0 0 1,121 l0,-5 a70,68 0 0 1 0,-110 l0,-5 z"/>
 </g></svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to fill background color to svg image in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52942450/7394871) от участника  [@M.Javid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10471100/m-javid).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52942450/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так можно посчитать точки пересечения окружностей, 
для конструирования пути

```js
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  let r = 51;
  let x = Math.sin(t/2010)*90;
  let y = Math.sin(t/1731)*40;
  let a = Math.atan2(y, x);
  let s = Math.acos(Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)/2/r);
  let p0 = [Math.cos(a+s)*r, Math.sin(a+s)*r];
  let p1 = [Math.cos(a-s)*r, Math.sin(a-s)*r];
  sun.setAttribute('d', `
      m${p0}
      A${r},${r},0,1,1,${p1}
      A${r},${r},0,0,0,${p0}
      z
  `);
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox=-55,-55,110,110 height=100vh width=100vw>
  <path id=sun stroke=teal fill=none stroke-width=2 stroke-linejoin=round></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Я бы сделал это с маской.

Так что, я могу сделать эллиптическую тень.

Пояснения смотрите в комментариях скрипта

```js
// Установить handler на input слайдера
var control = document.getElementById("control");
control.addEventListener("input", setMoonPhase);

// Инициализируйте SVG из начального значения слайдера
setMoonPhase();

function setMoonPhase(evt) {
  // Преобразовать из процента в значение 0..1
  var val = control.value / 100;
  // Получить элемент эллипса, который представляет фазу луны
  var  phaseEllipse = document.getElementById("phase-ellipse");
  // Установите радиус X фазового эллипса (где 100% = 0,5 -> 50% = 0 -> 0% = 0,5)
  phaseEllipse.rx.baseVal.value = Math.abs(val - 0.5);
  // Если фаза> 50%, то эллипс должен быть белым.
  // В противном случае это черный цвет, чтобы сделать дыру в маске, чтобы пропустить черный фон.
  phaseEllipse.style.fill = (val > 0.5) ? "white" : "black";
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="139" height="134">
  <defs>
    <mask id="phase-mask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <rect x="0.5" y="0" width="0.5" height="1" fill="white"/>
      <ellipse id="phase-ellipse" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" rx="0.2" ry="0.5" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle fill="black" r="58" cy="69" cx="69"/><!-- moon shadow -->
  <circle fill="#fff" r="54.5" cy="69" cx="69" mask="url(#phase-mask)"/><!-- sunlight on moon -->
  <circle stroke-width="7" stroke="black" fill="none" r="58" cy="69" cx="69"/><!-- moon border -->
</svg>
<p>
<input id="control" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="90" /><span id="output"></span>
</p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950656/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал это с помощью `clip-path`.

```js
mooning()


control.addEventListener("input",()=>{
mooning()
})


function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}

function mooning(){
output.innerHTML = control.value + "%";
let value = map(control.value, 0, 100, -25, 175)
moon.setAttributeNS(null, "cx", value)
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:75vh}
#control{width:75vh;}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150"> 
 <clipPath id="cp">
  <circle id="fullMoon"  r="50" cy="75" cx="75"/>
 </clipPath>
 <g clip-path="url(#cp)">
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" />  
 <circle id="moon" r="50" cy="75" cx="175" fill="white" />
 </g>
 
 <use xlink:href="#fullMoon" fill="none" stroke="black"  />
 
</svg>

<p><input id="control" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="60" /><span id="output"></span></p>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52946763/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

### Анимация окружностей

Я бы сделал это с применением анимации чёрной окружности, которая постепенно и открывает и снова закрывает светлую окружность.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"  viewBox="0 0 73 73" >
<defs>
 <radialGradient id="RadialGrad"
           fx="50%" fy="50%" r="65%"
           spreadMethod="pad">
          <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#E7D68C" stop-opacity="1"/>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#FFFEED" stop-opacity="1" />
        </radialGradient>

</defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" />
<g transform="rotate(-20 35.5 35.5)">
<circle cx="35.5" cy="35.5" r="35" stroke="none"  fill="url(#RadialGrad)" />

 <circle cx="35.5" cy="35.5" r="35" stroke="none" fill="black" >
 
 <animate id="youngMoon"
   attributeName="cx"
   values="35.5;-35.5;"
   begin="1s;oldMoon.end+1s"
   dur="10s"
   fill="freeze"
  />
<animate id="oldMoon"
   attributeName="cx"
   values="105;35.5;"
   begin="youngMoon.end+1s"
   dur="10s"
   fill="freeze" /> 

</circle> 
</g>
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58796787/7394871): @Alexandr_TT