# Полумесяц на CSS

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation, svg-animation

Как можно анимировать на `CSS` месяц?

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.icon {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(128,128,128, 1);
    border-right: 4px solid rgba(128,128,128, 1);
    transform: translate(25%, -50%) rotate(135deg);
    opacity: 0.5;
    animation: anime 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes anime {
  0% {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom: 8px solid rgba(128,128,128, 1);
    border-right: 8px solid rgba(128,128,128, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

Comment: Как именно нужно анимировать-то?

Comment: @andreymal не знаю, просто, как-нибудь, чтобы было интересно

Comment: «как-нибудь» это не по теме сайта

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044708/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-svg-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85

Comment: @Leks спасибо, как раз