# Как нарисовать пересечение кругов?

Tags: javascript

Пусть есть два круга, неизвестно как расположенных на плоскости. Допустим один из них красный, другой синий.

Каким образом я могу нарисовать их пересечение? Например, залив его жёлтым цветом.

Comment: SVG или canvas.

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/voBwJm

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1044834/188366

Comment: Какова конечная цель? Декоративная или мат.расчёты?

Comment: чтобы ученикам показывать взаимодействие между множествами. То есть только визуальная часть интересует

Comment: Ученикам показывать в Корел начертить можно и все. Зачем программу писать для статической картинки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что требуется. Если нужно только отобразить и выделить пересечение фигур, то всё просто. Для наглядности добавил перетаскивание на JS, но основа - это CSS и свойство `mix-blend-mode`, которое отвечает за цвет в месте пересечения:

```js
window.onload=function(){var oActive;function drag(){[...document.querySelectorAll('.circle')].forEach(function(el){el.onmousedown=function(ev){oActive=this;oActive.ondragstart=function(){return!1}
document.onmousemove=function(ev){oActive.style.left=oActive.offsetLeft+ev.movementX+'px';oActive.style.top=oActive.offsetTop+ev.movementY+'px'}
document.onmouseup=function(){document.onmousemove=document.onmouseup=null}}})}
drag()}
```

```css
body{position:relative;margin:0;height:100vh;overflow:hidden;background:linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0) .9em,rgba(0,0,0,.15) 1em) 0 0,linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(255,255,255,0) .9em,rgba(0,0,0,.15) 1em) 0 0;background-size:1em 1em;background-color:#fcfcff}

.circle {
  position: absolute; z-index: 1;
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%; border: 2px dotted grey;
  font: 24px Arial; color: black;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px white, 1px -1px 1px white, 1px 1px 1px white, -1px 1px 1px white;
  /* Свойство определяющее режим наложения цветов */
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.red {
  top: 5px; left: 200px;
  height: 150px; width: 150px;
  background: red;
}
.green {
  top: 70px; left: 300px;
  height: 120px; width: 120px;
  background: #8CC500;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
.blue {
  top: 5px; left: 315px;
  height: 90px; width: 190px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle red">A</div>
<div class="circle blue">C</div>
<div class="circle green">B</div>
```

Comment: ооо. то что нужно. спасибо